# Wordpress redirecting non-www to homepage

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress site is set up so that any time you remove the www from the url, it will take to back to the home page.

For SSL reasons, I need a single page to be accessed without the www.

Lets call it  test.org/page

Is there a custom redirect I can put in my htaccess, so that www.test.org/page is redirected to test.org/page? I'm using and old old version of wordpress with a redirection plugin and multisite.

Here is my current htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess file looks fine, I would leave it as is but in the back end check your:

Settings -> General

And make sure that both your WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) **doesn't** contain the www.

Hope this helps ;)